# Comparing an Arraylist with a list of classes c#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have a list of database items and a list of files.  I am trying to find out what files are missing from the database.  I read the database into a list DBItems.  I read the files into another list:

```
    List<DBFiles> DBItems = new List<DBFiles>();
    ArrayList FileArray =  Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\reports\", "*.rpt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    public class DBFiles
    {
        public DBFiles(string fileName, string flag)
        {
            this.FileName = fileName;
            this.Flag = flag;
        }
        public string FileName { set; get; }
        public string Flag { set; get; }
    }
```

My question is how do I look up if each item in FileArray is in DBFiles with a specific Flag.  This is what I have so far:

```
    private void ListCompare()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < FileArray.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DBItems.FileName.Contains(FileArray[i]) && DBItems.Flag.Contains("A") )
                {
                }


        }
    }
```

Obviously it's not working.  Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *Linq*: you want all the files in the directory `Except` the files in the `DBItems`:

```
   var result = Directory
     .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\reports\", "*.rpt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Except(DBItems
        .Where(item => item.Flag.Contains("A")) // add condition via Where in required
        .Select(item => item.FileName)
        ,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     .ToArray(); // let's materialize into array
```

P.S. Try avoiding *obsolete* `ArrayList` class; put `List<T>` (`List<string>` in your case) instead.

**Edit:** according to the question refines (see comments) below the condition is more complicated.

> I'm looking for files that start with h9347 (the database defines only
>   the first part of the file name for client specific needs

In this case I suggest creating a `HashSet<string>` of what to exclude, and again use *Linq*:

```
// File names in name.extension format to exclude 
HashSet<string> toExclude = new HashSet<string>(DBItems
  .Where(item => item.Flag.Contains("A")
  .Select(item => item.FileName),
  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

var result => Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\reports\", "*.rpt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Where(file => Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith("h9347") &&
                 !toExclude.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file)))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I changed to List<T>.  This almost works.  Please help as I am not good at LINQ.  The other criteria is that the filename cannot be in DBItems.  I am getting all the files in the directory.  I am looking to get all the filenames in the directory that are not in DBItems.FileName.  Thank you for your help Dmitry.

Comment: @Missy: does `DBItems.FileName` include *directory name*? In other words is `DBItems.FileName` a `C:\MyText.txt` or just `MyText.txt`?

Comment: Actually, ultimately it will contain a portion of the file name so I'm looking for files that start with h9347 (the database defines only the first part of the file name for client specific needs).  No paths.  I revised your code to change this:  Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\reports\", "*.rpt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) to FileArray because I massage FileArray a bit to get rid of duplicates.   That part worked.

Comment: @Missy: in this case, I suggest creating `HashSet<string> toExclude` collection of which file names should be excluded; then use *Linq* to filter out these files from `Directory.EnumerateFiles`